# MultiDataTrigger does not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I want to have a MultiDataTrigger for my TabControl. When the tab is hovered it should change the color. But not if the Tab is selected. I tried a MultiDataTrigger. But it does not seem to work. Here is my Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Grid>
                <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5,0.5,0.5,0" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#fefeff" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#e7edf6" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#c5d0df" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#aab4c2" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#dde6f2" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#c6d0de" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTriggers use the `DataContext` as the source. And I am sure that `IsMouseOver` and `IsSelected` are not properties from your data context, they are properties of the tab item.

I suggest use normal `MultiTrigger` with normal `Trigger` `Condition`s in it.

Answer (score 4):

Change your trigger to be:

```
<MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
</MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

As per [AngelWPF's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886048/multidatatrigger-does-not-work/7886357#7886357) answer a DataTrigger will attempt to bind to the current DataContext, where it will find nothing matching the properties.

Comment: @Anonymous you're using MultiDataTriggers, not MultiTriggers